# where put slugify method for symfony2 entities

Tags: php, oop, symfony, design-patterns, doctrine-orm

I have slugify method that slugify title attribute of entity class every time it change.
so I put this method in entity class and call it like this:

```
public function setTitle($t){
  $this->title = $t;
  $this->slugTitle = $this->slugify($t);
}
```

it work fine for me, but if I have **more than one class** that use slugify method I should put this method in all of them, and this is code duplication.

so what should i do? if use helper class I cannot use slugify() like upper method :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick fix you can create some sort of `%Bundle%/Utils/Utils.php` class (which can be static), put the function in there and use it like

```
use MyBundle/Utils/Utils;

class Someclass {
// ...
$this->slugTitle = Utils::slugify($t);
```

A more sophisticated approach would be using [Gedmo's Doctrine Extensions](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst). It handles that behaviour for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Doctrine event listener/subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) to listen to entity changes and act on them.

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class SlugifyListener
{
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        // do something with $entity...
    }
}
```

<kbd>services.xml</kbd>:

```
<service id="my.listener" class="Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\SlugifyListener">
    <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="preUpdate" />
</service>
```

However in this case, you're better off taking a look at the [Doctrine Extensions bundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle). It provides a Sluggable extension which can do this for you, rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I agree with this, the "correct OOP approach" OP is looking for is writing a LifecycleEvent listener, and injecting it with some helper functions

Answer (score 0):

There is a package that you can you to do this for you.

It is called [Sluggable behavior extension for Doctrine 2](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md)

Comment: thanks for the link, but I want to know what is best OOP practice for situation like this

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a base class with your slugify function in (infact the whole setTitle could be in the base class if all your children have a title and needs slugging) and then inherit from it for all your entity classes?

```
class slugclass{

  $title
  $slugtitle

  public function setTitle($t){
      $this->title = $t;
      $this->slugTitle = $this->slugify($t);
  }

  public function slugify($t){
     ...sluggify code
  }

}


class childentity extends slugclass{

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, cuz my entities have different logic I don't think this is best practice to have same supper class just for slugify  :-/

Comment: yeah if all your entities are very conceptually different then one of the other approaches is definitely better, always good to offer up the easiest path though in case its appropriate.