# Symfony create slug from entitys title

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, slug

I have a working blog but I thought a bit late about nice urls.

I dont want to use slugable and so on bundles because I dont have much time to read documentations and implement them.

Is it possible to reach a field of an entity and generate the slug from that before doctrine executes into the db?

I thought of an easy solution in the entity like:

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->setPostedAt(new \DateTime());
        $this->setSlug();
    }
public function setSlug(){
        $tmpslug = (string)$this->id."-";
        $tmpslug .= $this->slugify($this->title);

        $this->slug = $tmpslug;
    }
```

However this will not work as the id and title fields are empty when the construct() called.

Is there any fast solution which wouldnt require to implement a new extension?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [where put slugify method for symfony2 entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442048/where-put-slugify-method-for-symfony2-entities)

Answer (score 5):

I dont' think Sluggable (from DoctrineExtensions) will take more time than reinventing the ready wheel.. I'd use it, it takes 10 minutes to be ready to use.

1. add `"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev"` to `composer.json`
2. add configs to the `config.yml`:

config:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            uploadable: false
            sluggable: true
            timestampable: false
            translatable: false
            tree: false
            blameable: false
            loggable: false
            sortable: false
            softdeleteable: false
```

3. add `slug` field and getter/setter to your entity

code:

```
private $slug;
public function getSlug() {...}
public function setSlug($slug) {...}
```

4. add `xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping"` to `doctrine-mapping` section in your ENTITY.orm.xml (if you're using xml)
5. add slug field to your ENTITY.orm.xml (if you're using xml);

code:

```
<field name="slug" column="slug" type="string">
    <gedmo:slug fields="title(OR_YOUR_DESIRED_FIELD)" unique="true" updatable="true" />
</field>
```

that's it, you can forget about it, you don't need to set, event listeners will take care about it..

Answer (score 0):

Okey..Just forgot Lifecycle Callbacks function of doctrine.
So the answer is not to put the function call inside the constructor rather update the function with the mapping information:

```
/**
    * @ORM\PrePersist
    * @ORM\PreUpdate
    */
    public function setSlug(){
        $tmpslug = (string)$this->id."-";
        $tmpslug = $this->slugify($this->title);

        $this->slug = $tmpslug;
    }
```

also not forget to update the entity mapping

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
```